Is temperature same for same final pressure and volume?
I have a doubt regarding temperature changes in various thermodynamic procces. Lets say if a gas has initial pressure p1 and volume v1 and has final pressure p2 and volume v2 then according to pv =nrT if p2 and v2 are kept same for different process then T should also be same. But I read somewhere that final temperature depends if the process is reversible or irreversible.

Final temperature of ideal gas depends on whether its energy  has changes. If work and heat are prevented, energy can't change, and thus temperature can't change. If heat or work are allowed, then energy can change, and thus temperature can change.

Suppose that the temperature of the surroundings is the same as the initial temperature of the gas. Irrespective of whether the process is irreversible or reversible, the product of p and v at final equilibrium must be the same (for an ideal gas). Of course the amount of work done and the amount of heat exchanged with the surroundings will be different for reversible and irreversible paths, and for a real gas, the product of p and v does not have to be the same).

Temperature is a thermodynamic property. The change in temperature between two equilibrium states does not depend on the process.
Your example where the product of the pressure and volume is the same for the initial and final equilibrium states could be the result of either a reversible or irreversible process.
The reversible process would be an isothermal (constant temperature) compression or expansion of an ideal gas. An example of an irreversible process is a free expansion of an ideal gas in a rigid insulated container. Because it’s irreversible the temperature during the process is not constant. But the initial and final equilibrium temperatures are the same satisfying the ideal gas equation.
Hope this helps.
